# Error in amazon S3 samples

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Hello Everyone,
           I am using amazon s3 bucket in a site. And in the amazon SDK for PHP given [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/), is not running the samples after changing the values in config file(config-sample.inc.php). And as per the instruction, i tried to view this page after set the values of `key` and `secret` values. `_samples/cli-s3_get_urls_for_uploads.php` which is showing the error as follows.
[image: Amazon SDK error in sample]

Any help regarding this to solve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4261?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1):

> 1. Navigate to the config-sample.inc.php file in the SDK directory, and **rename it to config.inc.php**.